# apply fitted model to data and obtain loglikelihood

Tags: python

I would like to do the following in Python, preferably with the statsmodels package (but if you know a solution with another package, I would be glad to hear about it as well):
I have data `olddata` and predictors `predictors`. I used

```
import statsmodels.api as sta 
model = sta.GLM(olddata,predictors,family=sta.families.Binomial())
fitted = model.fit()
loglikelihood = fitted.llf
```

to fit a model and obtain the loglikelihood. Now I would like to find out, how well this fitted model describes a new dataset `newdata`. If I just used

```
loglikelihood = sta.GLM(newdata,predictors,family=sta.families.Binomial()).fit().llf
```

I would of course just obtain the loglikelihood for a fitted model with new weights for my new data. What I would like to obtain, however, is the llhood for the old model given the new data. I would be glad, if someone could tell me how this can be done without manually calculating the loglikelihood.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to change the data in a model, however the loglikelihood can be evaluated for any parameters.

In this case, we can create a new model with the new data, but evaluate the `model.loglike` at the old parameter estimate, something like

```
model_new = sta.GLM(newdata, predictors, family=sta.families.Binomial())
llf2 = model_new.loglike(fitted_old.params)
```

where `fitted_old` is the old estimation results instance.

This should work with statsmodels master, but I don't remember when loglike was added to work this way.

Note, `result_instance.llf` is the value of the loglikelihood at the estimate, `model_instance.loglike` is the method that can be evaluated at any `params`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your kind answer. I tried `model_new = sta.GLM(newdata, predictors, family=sta.families.Binomial())` and  `fitted_old = sta.GLM(olddata, predictors, family=sta.families.Binomial()).fit()` , but then `llf2 = model_new.loglike(fitted_old.params)` yielded "loglike() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)". The documentation only mentions, that *args are needed, but not what args exactly. I tried `family=...` , which didn't work out. fitted_old.params looks reasonable, though, being a 1d-vector containing the coefficients for my predictors.

Comment: Ok, statsmodels 0.6.1 has the old version where loglike is directly defined through the family loglikelihood which takes the predicted mean as argument. It's just a few lines, however, if your response variable is a binary 0,1 variable and not a count, then you could use `Logit` which defines model.loglike(params)

Comment: Are your old and new predictors the same, and just the response changes?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the same predictors with the coefficients from fitted_old and just get their likelihood for new data