# Probability (density) of new dataset under fitted model

Tags: r, lm, lme4

Given a fitted model in R (i.e. an object of class 'lm', 'glm', 'merMod', etc), I am trying to figure out how to calculate the probability of a new dataset.

That is, I want the probability (density) of dataset B under the parameter estimates obtained by fitting a model to dataset A.  I know how to do this in general, but I am wondering whether a simple pre-existing function can do this in R. Is there a simple function to do this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242037/apply-fitted-model-to-data-and-obtain-loglikelihood) is very similar, but I want to do this in R.

Answer (score 0):

for a linear regression model `lm`, you could use the following function to determine and visualize the likelihood, assuming the residuals of linear model fit is normally distributed (these functions were adapted from [this R Blogger Post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-model-by-maximum-likelihood/); rationale of the procedure can be found in [this post](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/linear-regression-maximum-likelihood)):

```
log_lik <- function(beta0, beta1, mu, sigma) {
  ## beta0 and beta1 require intial guesses
  R <- y - x * beta1 - beta0
  R <- dnorm(R, mu, sigma, log=T)
  return(-sum(R))
}
library(stats4)
fit <- mle(log_lik, start=list(beta0=4, beta1=2, mu = 0, sigma=1))
summary(fit)
## mu will be your estimated likelihood
## sigma will be uncertainty
```

For `glm`, [this post in Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72060/log-likelihood-for-glm) provides user-defined R functions for the likelihood.

(ps: It would be nice if you could provide a specific example involving one of `lm`, `glm`, etc. If you just want to know these models in general, Cross Validated, Mathematics, or Data Science might be better places to ask.)